# Add custom packages to Azure Machine Learing Studio

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to use the function tsCV on azure machine learning studio to evaluate models of forecast, but i got the error

```
could not find function "tsCV
```

I'm trying to update the forecast package, but no package are loaded.
I followed this tutorial
http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/10/using-minicran-in-azure-ml.html
and 
https://blog.tallan.com/2016/12/27/adding-r-packages-in-azure-ml/
but i dont get the same result.
No packages are load.

I need an example of a package with R code that works o Azure ML or an update of forecast package to use tsCV function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed the latest version of the forecast package and here are the steps I followed during the installation.

1. Download latest version of CRAN
2. Be sure that tsCV is working locally
3. Zip all the dependencies + forecast package
4. Zip all the generated zips together and upload it to the AMLStudio
5. Run the following code:

> ```
> install.packages("src/glue.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/stringi.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/assertthat.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/fansi.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/utf8.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/stringr.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/labeling.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/munsell.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/R6.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/RColorBrewer.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/cli.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/crayon.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/pillar.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/xts.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/TTR.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/curl.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/digest.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/gtable.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/lazyeval.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/plyr.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/reshape2.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/rlang.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/scales.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/tibble.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/viridisLite.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/withr.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/quadprog.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/quantmod.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/colorspace.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/fracdiff.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/ggplot2.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/lmtest.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/magrittr.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/Rcpp.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/timeDate.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/tseries.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/urca.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/uroot.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/zoo.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/RcppArmadillo.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> install.packages("src/forecast.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
>
> library(forecast, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
> far2 <- function(x, h){forecast(Arima(x, order=c(2,0,0)), h=h)}
> e <- tsCV(lynx, far2, h=1)
> ```

[Here is the zip I have generated:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Bj0RGCmRFrRECLQrVc26nbx3T-bNSL6)

[image: My experiment]

Comment: Yes! it works! Just 2 questions. How did you found the dependencies? Is really necessary to install all packages every time i run a script? That takes too much time...

Comment: Great! Actually it is even not necessary to install all the dependencies. Just start by forecast, and if it fails open the output log and install the dependencies step by step. For instance, for quanteda package, out of 12 dependencies only 2 were actually needed. E.G. Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called 'ca', thus we need to install ca before quanteda, etc.

Comment: And to find the dependencies I have removed all the previously installed packages and tracked the installation log