# Loading R packages that are not supported under CRAN3.1 while creating a custom module in azure ML

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am creating a custom module in Azure ML studio which will use the `kNN` function of VIM package for missing data imputation. However the VIM package is not supported under CRAN3.1 in azure ML or in other words this package is not available by default in ML studio. So the newly created custom module gives an error in loading VIM package when I run the experiment using the custom module.

Is there any way in which I can make VIM available within the context of the custom module?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation you can add zip input. In your XML file you need to add:

```
 <Input id="zippedData" name="Zip Input" type="Zip" IsOptional="false">
    <Description>Zip files to be extracted to the R working directory.</Description>
   </Input>
```

which will allow using external packages. And inside your source file (implementing all the R logic) you should add :

```
install.packages("src/vim.zip", lib = ".", repos=NULL, verbose=TRUE)
library(VIM, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
```

I would suggest installing VIM beforehand in order to check if it works in a standard R module. If it works, then it should definitely work in your custom module because, as the documentation says:

> The execution environment for the R script uses the same version of R as the Execute R Script module and can use the same default packages. You can also add additional R packages to your custom module by including them in the custom module zip package. Just load them in your R script as you would in your own R environment.

You may find my post on how to install custom R packages [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278613/add-custom-packages-to-azure-machine-learing-studio/52369384#52369384)